# Visual studio and object instance bug

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, debugging, instance

[image: Example Bug]

As you can see on the screenshot. When I try to browse the parametrage object, Visual Studio debugging and bug stops.

```
    Dim parametrage = New ParametrageView()
    Dim container As hCtrlPanelsPanel = parametrage.Controls.Item("StepsContainer")
    Dim header As GradientBar = parametrage.Controls.Item("InformationLabel")
    Dim etape = New GeneralViewStep()

    parametrage.ChangedStep(etape)

    Check.That(container.ActiveCtrlPanel).IsEqualTo(etape)
    Check.That(header.Text).IsEqualTo(etape.InformationMessage)
```

However, I do not understand because the object is instantiated and I can even call a method as in the test when I call the method ChangedStep.

The ParameterView class is a simple user control in its constructor with only the InitializeComponent method.

If you have an idea of what can cause this error because I'm interested in the absence of an exception that rises and Visual Studio bug that during debugging I can not find the source of the problem

Comment: Well before the breakpoint are 2 function calls (both to ::Controls.Item()) and a constructor call for GeneralViewStep; Perhaps the error is caused in one of those.

Comment: Set a brekpoint on each line of your test function and determine when the object becomes invalid.

Comment: I tried to put a breakpoint on the previous lines. No bug, I recovers an empty variable because I can not browse the ParametrageView object.
No error is raised though the object appears as empty. However he did not.

Comment: When I run my test, method runs but not restore user control of the object. It's incomprehensible. I should not be able to call a method if the object is empty.

Comment: Check for circular references in your object, especially in property getters. I had the same issue and the reason was I referenced an object in property A which lead to a call to property B which lead to call again property A...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: List of controls user]

I have read the complete list of user controls parametrage object. And I discovered a problem. Only 2 controls its present while as you could see in the list of control designer there's more. It seems that all the controls are not instantiated.

Comment: So I think i solve this problem. It's my fault. I have completely forgotten but I using a split container to create the bofy of my form. And I browse only the controls of my form while  i must to browse the controls of my splitcontainer for recover the other controls